# Tile/Greographic Map in Kibana not working

Tags: debian, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to create a geographical map of my data in `Kibana` 5.01, and it does not work. The fact is that I do not even have the `geoip.field` that is required in the menu.

I am sending data from IntelMQ, that is processed by `logstash` to get into elastic search. In the fields received I only have `source_ip`

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For passing geographical data to `elasticsearch`, there is a need to create a `logstash` filter to process the field referencing the IP address, and creating new field(s) with geographical data.

Based on this article [How To Map User Location with GeoIP and ELK?](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-map-user-location-with-geoip-and-elk-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana)

My new `/etc/logstash/conf.d` is:

```
filter {
  geoip {
    source => "source_ip"
    target => "geoip"
    database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
    add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
    add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
  }
  mutate {
    convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
  }
}
```

After applying this log, there is a need to restart `logstash` and double check the logs at `/var/log/logstash`.

So the end result is:

[image: map]

Comment: Is it also possible to use the longitude and latitude of the intelmq-event itself (and use the maxmind-geoip expert)?