# geoip logstash filter not working in Debian

Tags: debian, geolocation, logstash

I am trying to setup the `geoip` filter for `logstash`in Debian Stretch, as per this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326199/tile-greographic-map-in-kibana-not-working)

I installed the `geoip-database` package, however `logstash` logs complain of wrong database format. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the databases that come with the `geoip-database` package *and* that are downloaded by `geoip-database-contrib` are in a older format not expected by the `geoip` filter of `logstash`.

I downloaded the version 2 free database from the maxmind site with the command:

```
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz
gunzip GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz
mv GeoLite2-City.mmdb /etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat
```

Restarted logstash, and now it does not complain about the GeoLite file being in the wrong format.